# Regex to split Git log with Python

Tags: python, string, git, split

I want to use python `import re` to split the string of Git's log as below:

```
commit 8e018dbcdbff15c3fc9ef4460b4214f47f71ddf6
Author: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>
Date:   Fri Apr 28 18:58:00 2023 +0800

    new cat

commit 9274b33435238122c8d6d389e73266f6a3e68745
Author: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>
Date:   Wed Apr 19 11:04:04 2023 +0800

    meow

commit 4f113912741f753c75a44f18790ff5903e910fad
Author: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>
Date:   Fri Apr 14 17:55:55 2023 +0800

    Add test files

commit 9274b33435238122c8d6d389e73266f6a3e68745
Author: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>
Date:   Wed Apr 19 11:04:04 2023 +0800

    Second commit test

commit 9274b33435238122c8d6d389e73266f6a3e68745
Author: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>
Date:   Wed Apr 19 11:04:04 2023 +0800

    First commit
```

Then,

I want to get commits array as below:

```py
[
'
commit 8e018dbcdbff15c3fc9ef4460b4214f47f71ddf6
Author: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>
Date:   Fri Apr 28 18:58:00 2023 +0800

    new cat

',
'
commit 9274b33435238122c8d6d389e73266f6a3e68745
Author: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>
Date:   Wed Apr 19 11:04:04 2023 +0800

    meow

',
...
]
```

It's hard to find the pattern which is Clean and General to match a commit for me.

Comment: I think it would be more accurate, though more time-consuming, to get the commit sha1 values first and then retrieve each commit's meta data one by one.

Comment: do you have control on the `git log` command that generates this output ? another way could be to specify your own `--pretty` option and have it generate something that is easy to split on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame the problem as **locating blocks with known start/end patterns**.

Then, define where the block start and end - here by **anchoring to commit hashes**.

```py
import re

rgx = r'(commit\s[0-9,a-f]{40}.*?)(?=commit\s[0-9,a-f]{40}|\Z)'

text = '''commit 8e018dbcdbff15c3fc9ef4460b4214f47f71ddf6
Author: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>
Date:   Fri Apr 28 18:58:00 2023 +0800

    new cat

commit 9274b33435238122c8d6d389e73266f6a3e68745
Author: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>
Date:   Wed Apr 19 11:04:04 2023 +0800

    meow

commit 4f113912741f753c75a44f18790ff5903e910fad
Author: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>
Date:   Fri Apr 14 17:55:55 2023 +0800

    Add test files

commit 87053deb6ad07fa1ea6dd7a5acfee075ce5b6322
Author: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>
Date:   Fri Apr 14 15:16:57 2023 +0800

    Add cat.jpg
'''

re.findall(rgx, text, re.DOTALL)
```

which gives the expected output

```
['commit 8e018dbcdbff15c3fc9ef4460b4214f47f71ddf6\nAuthor: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>\nDate:   Fri Apr 28 18:58:00 2023 +0800\n\n    new cat\n\n',
 'commit 9274b33435238122c8d6d389e73266f6a3e68745\nAuthor: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>\nDate:   Wed Apr 19 11:04:04 2023 +0800\n\n    meow\n\n',
 'commit 4f113912741f753c75a44f18790ff5903e910fad\nAuthor: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>\nDate:   Fri Apr 14 17:55:55 2023 +0800\n\n    Add test files\n\n',
 'commit 87053deb6ad07fa1ea6dd7a5acfee075ce5b6322\nAuthor: ISAAC.NEWTON <ISAAC.NEWTON@GOOGLE.COM>\nDate:   Fri Apr 14 15:16:57 2023 +0800\n\n    Add cat.jpg\n']
```

EDIT: **mind the EOF** handled with the sentinel `\Z`

Comment: The final lookahead prevents matching the last commit.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try to use re.split,like this:

```
import re    
text = git.logs()
ret = re.split('\n', text)
ret_u_want = ['\n'.join(ret[i:i+6]) for i in range(0, len(ret), 6)]
```

And you can just use split func of list without re:

```
 text = git.logs()
 ret = text.split('\n')
 ret_u_want = ['\n'.join(ret[i:i+6]) for i in range(0, len(ret), 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t
need to use a regex if you are the one who is generating the output. You
can split on the null byte instead.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

log = subprocess.check_output(["git", "log", "-z"]).decode().split("\x00")
print(log)
```

Or at least I’ve never seen such a control character in a commit message.

Comment: I initially wrote an answer indicating you could use `--format` to set a custom separator and possibly avoid using a regexp at all, but this is even more straightforward and blunder free.